# How to Export Outlook tasks into Excel within a specified date range (VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, vba

**Problem**
I am fairly new to VBA and currently putting together a piece of code that extracts all Microsoft Outlook Tasks into a new excel sheet. So far the VBA code works well, except I can't get it to only extract data within a user specified date.

**Specs**
Microsoft Outlook/Excel 2010, 
Windows 7

Here's the extract of the non working code:

```
'VBA MACRO WHICH RUNS IN OUTLOOK 
 --------------
Dim strStart As Date
Dim strEnd As Date

strStart = InputBox("Enter a start date using the following format MM/DD/YYYY", "Input  Required")
strEnd = InputBox("Enter a due date using the following format MM/DD/YYYY", "Input  Required")

strQuery = "[DueDate] >= 'strStart' AND [DueDate] <= 'strEnd'"
Set OlkList = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Items.Restrict(strQuery)
```

Comment: I'm not confident with outlook data types, so it's may not be the final answer, but surely your logic including variants literally is wrong, you should you something like `"[DueDate] >= '" & strStart & "' AND [DueDate] <= '" & strEnd & "'"`

Comment: Thanks a lot:)  

That was very helpful and now it now works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert your variants literally in your criteria, instead of inserting their values, to fix use this:

`"[DueDate] >= '" & strStart & "' AND [DueDate] <= '" & strEnd & "'"`

Comment: Thanks :). That really cleared things up and resolve it.

  Unfortunately I cannot upvote your answer (since I just registered on this website today, but I will be sure to do so as my rep increases)